# What is a "mono wrapper"?

Tags: mono, interface

I am a Linux enthusiast with some very basic programming experience and I am currently trying to set up a touch surface interface using Microsoft's Kinect and Simple Kinect Touch software. I am in the process of building the software and was just wondering if anyone could tell me what a "Mono Wrapper" is. The README file tells you that it is optional to install this with the software but I am curious none the less :P.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also it would be nice to know why this question got "down" voted so I can make sure that I ask better questions in future. :)

Comment: It was most likely down voted because it is not Ubuntu related

Comment: Yeah I suppose so, I think I've started thinking of ask ubuntu as a general Q&A site when its not really. I'll try to keep this in mind in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mono-wrapper is just a layer on top of a library allowing you to use the library with mono.

Answer (score 0):

Mono is an open source .net framework  http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page